# Cannot have first parameter as optional

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Can you have a function with and optional parameter as the first and only parameter?

thus

`(defn foo [& bar] (if (= bar) 1 2))`

Comment: `(= x)` in clojure is always `true`, no matter what `x` is, as long as `x` doesn't disrupt execution of the form by throwing an exception

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What `& bar` means at function definition is that all the rest of the arguments will be put into a list. It does not give any guarantees as to the size of the list, so it could be empty, with one or more items.

A better approach to having one and only optional argument, is to have it accept zero or one arguments:

```
(defn foo
   ([]    (foo 12))
   ([bar] (if (= bar 12) 1 2)))
```

In this example, if you call the first function definition, with zero arity, it will simply call the second 1-arity function definition with a default value of 12.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
(defn foo [& bar]
  (if (seq bar) 1 2))
```

Using `seq` is the way you are supposed to code 'not empty'. Not to be confused with `seq?`, which means something quite different, which will in fact return `true` here.

The important point is that `bar` becomes a list inside the function body. If you want to get this list back to what it was when you called the function then use `apply`, or deconstruct the list in the function itself, as being explained in the comments below...

Comment: A common pattern is `[& [bar]]` which destructs the first parameter and makes it optional.

Comment: @ClojureMostly But that causes any additional arguments to be silently ignored, which can cause subtle bugs like [this](https://github.com/magomimmo/modern-cljs/issues/373).